# Reference request for poisson group actions which are not hamiltonian

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, poisson-geometry

Hamiltonian Lie group actions of Poisson manifolds are well studied and found everywhere in literature. I am wondering if there is any material available on what is known about Poisson actions in general (here by "in general" I am referring to actions which do not preserve the symplectic foliation so that they shuffle leaves of the foliation around). The problem does not seem completely intractable, as such Poisson structures would have to have very particular symplectic foliations. Is there any literature on this? If not is there a good reason why not?